# Kafka user - project design advise

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams, hazelcast-jet

I am new to Kafka and data streaming and need some advice for the following requirement,
Our system is expecting close to 1 million incoming messages per day. The message carries a project identifier. The message should be pushed to users of only that project. For our case, lets say we have projects A, B and C. Users who opens project A's dashboard only sees / receives messages of project A.

This is my idea so far on implementing solution for the requirement,

The messages should be pushed to a Kafka Topic as they arrive, lets call this topic as Root Topic. The messages once pushed to the Root Topic, can be read by a Kafka Consumer/Listener and based on the project identifier in the message can push that message to a project specific Topic. So any message can end up at Topic A or B or C. Thinking of using websockets to update the message as they arrive on the project users' dashboards. There will be N Consumers/Listeners for the N project Topics. These consumers will push the project specific message to the project specifc websocket endpoints.

Please advise if I can make any improvements to the above design.

Chose Kafka as the messaging system here as it is highly scalable and fault tolerant.

There is no complex transformation or data enrichment before it gets sent to the client. Will it makes sense to use Apache Flink or Hazelcast Jet for the streaming or Kafka streaming is good enough for this simple requirement.

Also, when should I consider using Hazelcast Jet or Apache Flink in my project.

Should i use Flink say when I have to update few properties in the message based on a web service call or database lookup before sending it to the users?

Should I use Hazelcast Jet **only when** I need the entire dataset in memory to arrive at a property value? or will using Jet bring some benefits even for my simple use case specified above. Please advise.

Comment: Hazelcast Jet supports infinite stream transformations so it's not just for entire-dataset operations. Do note that "one million messages per day" is considered very low traffic. These systems are built to handle several million _per second_.

Comment: Thanks Marko, I was thinking of using Spring JMS Listener to listen to messages from an external (Not Kafka) Topic, Your suggestion is I use Jet here for infinite streams as in my case the source is an external messaging Topic and there is no definite end to the stream being processed. Will try this.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Streams are a great tool to convert one Kafka topic to another Kafka topic.

What you need is a tool to move data from a Kafka topic to another system via web sockets.

Stream processor gives you a convenient tooling to build this data pipeline (among others connectors to Kafka and web sockets and scalable, fault-tolerant execution environment). So you might want use stream processor even if you don't transform the data.

The benefit of Hazelcast Jet is it's embedded scalable caching layer. You might want to cache your database/web service calls so that the enrichment is performed locally, reducing remote service calls.

See how to use Jet to [read from Kafka](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-code-samples/blob/0.5-maintenance/streaming/kafka-source/src/main/java/KafkaSource.java) and how to write data to a [TCP socket](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-code-samples/blob/0.5-maintenance/streaming/socket-connector/src/main/java/WriteTextSocket.java) (not websocket).

Comment: Thanks Vlado, moving the messages from the Root Topic to the project Topics is what I am looking for. We will be using a dev cluster. I thought we are supposed to create project Topics and Kafka takes care of replication for fault tolerance. The Project Topic Consumers are supposed to read from project specific topics and push to websocket. Planning to use Spring-Websocket for sending messages to web browser so that number of users can connect to this project specific dashboards (web page) to see the respective messages.

Comment: Hello,

Kafka Streams seems to be a most convenient tool for moving data from Root Topic to Product topic as this is it's puropose.

Regarding Dashboards: does it mean that every web socket client (web browser) receives the complete message history after it connects? This may lead to massive data transfer with every reconnect. Moreover, you're basically implementing a stream processor in a web browser. Although it may be a proper design, consider using proper stream processor to prepare project dashboard. This dashboard may be stored in a str. proc. and consumed via WS to reduce traffic.

Comment: You are right Vlado, complete message history should not be sent back to User, there must be a filtering criteria, will use stream processor as you have advised. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give you another option. I'm not Spark/Jet expert at all, but I've studying them for a few weeks.

I would use [Pentaho Data Integration(kettle)](https://community.hds.com/docs/DOC-1009931-downloads) to consume from the Kafka and I would write a kettle step (or User Defined Java Class step) to write the messages to a Hazelcast IMAP.

Then, would use this approach http://www.c2b2.co.uk/middleware-blog/hazelcast-websockets.php to provided the Websockets for the end-users.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Kleyson, not sure I can convince my team to use Kettle for writing messages to Hazelcast. Thank you for the link on websockets with Hazelcast.